# Wrap CLI command in symfony command and pass arguments unparsed

Tags: symfony, console

Is there a way to pass all the input on the command line as a single argument to a console command? I am basically trying to write a console application that has one command that is simply a wrapper around a CLI command (drush). So I'd like to be able to let users type

```
myapp drush some drush arguments maybe a --flag-too
```

And have it pass everything after "drush" to the DrushCommand class. I'll then run it as a process and pass the whole string along.

The closest I've come is looking at the events dispatcher which allows me to see the unparsed input, but I don't see how to change it before the arguments are parsed.